# The square root of $x$ squared

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $ 1.   \sqrt {(x^2)}= x  \\ 2.   \sqrt {(x^2)}= |x|$

Second statment is true $\sqrt {(x^2)}= |x|$
but first statment i confused if is true or false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  first statment is false?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, $9$ has two square roots, but $\sqrt{9}$ is by definition the positive one - it does not have two values.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I didn't understand, why first statement not false

Comment: The statement $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ is false for negative values of $x$, but true for positive values for $x$ and for $x=0$. Without specifying what you mean by $x$, you cannot say whether the statement is true or false. It is certainly not always true, unlike $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ which is always true for any value of $x$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I understand, thank you

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The standard convention in calculus and higher level too is that $\sqrt{t}$, for $t\ge0$, denotes the only nonnegative $u$ such that $u^2=0$. Multivalued functions are used, but in special contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"First statement false" means there exists at least one counter example where statement is false.

counter example is $x = -3.$

Note: the only way that statements 1 and 2 can be meaningful, and thus permit evaluation is if

$\sqrt{x} : x \geq 0$ is **unambiguously** defined.

Therefore, **some convention** must be adopted.

The convention that has been adopted is that $\sqrt{x} : x \geq 0$ will **always** be presumed to be non-negative.